# What is this intake bottom the wing of C-5 and why is it placed there?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, feature-identification

There are two intakes bottom the wings of C-5. What are those and why are they placed there?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This C-5 cutaway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIZnp.jpg) indicates it's a "Heat Exchanger Inlet (76)" or "Ground Cooling Fan (78)"

EDIT: Upon closer inspection of this [higher-res image](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/69/82/b5/6982b59b537764286baab2bbe55d1c9a.gif), it may be the intake for the Ground Cooling Fan.

[image: C-5 Cutaway]